# Xor operation inversion python

Tags: python, string, numbers, xor

I have a string and a key. I'm converting each character into a number and corresponding character in key also to a number and performing XOR, then converting back into a character.

How can I invert it, since sometimes the XOR of a single character returns multiple characters?

```
def xor(plain):
    master = open('encrypt.py', 'r')
    key = master.readline()
    cipher = ""
    for x in range(0, len(plain)):
        cipher += chr(ord(plain[x]) ^ ord(key[x]))
    return cipher
```

Comment: What do you mean by "sometimes a single character xor gives multiple characters"? Can you give an example?

Comment: Are you sure you should be reading this in text mode? And what happens if you run out of key?

Comment: ord("a")^ord("b") gives 3 and chr(3) is '\x03'

Comment: the length of key is not a problem here as inputs are always of less length.

Comment: I concur with @user2357112, the file shall be read in the binary mode.

Comment: `'\x03'` is one character.

Comment: As a side note, the file with the key should not have the `.py` extension.

Comment: its ok im just testing it

Comment: \x03 is one charateher right what if u have multiple of those like \x03\x04 the code might not take it right.